# std::remove_const<std::unordered map> doesn't seem to be working

Tags: constants, c++20, unordered-map

```
void foo( const std::unordered_map<char, int> & m )
{
    using M = std::remove_const< decltype( m ) >;
    M mutable_map;
    mutable_map['a'] = 42;
}
```

This fails with "no match for operator[]". In my actual code I carry the map inside an `std::pair` and there the error message is clearer: "passing `const std::unordered_map<...>` as `this` discards qualifiers".

What's wrong? I can't use `const_cast<>()` because I don't know the type (the map template parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is that you are using `std::remove_const` instead of:
`std::remove_const::type`  or `std::remove_const_t`.

Second problem is that you need a value, not a reference, so you need discard also a reference, so you need `std::decay_t`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7KfPrGnaE)

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

void foo( const std::unordered_map<char, int> & m )
{
    using M = std::decay_t< decltype( m ) >;
    M mutable_map;
    mutable_map['a'] = 42;
}
```